Flutter: Deleting a file and updating MediaStore without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
In my Flutter application, I want users to be able to delete a music file and have Android MediaStore recognize this change. When I have the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, I can successfully delete the file without any issues. However, without this permission, the file deletion fails and I receive the following error:
 PathNotFoundException: Cannot delete file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Fatih 
 Bulut & Elmas - Gör Bak.mp3' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)



 void getFilePath(File file, BuildContext context, int index) {
  log('file '+ file.toString());  
  try {
  if (file.existsSync()) {
    index = Provider.of<PlayerStateles>(context, listen: false).currentIndex;

    file.deleteSync();
  
    OnAudioQuery _audioQuery = OnAudioQuery();
    _audioQuery.scanMedia(file.path); 

    Provider.of<PlayerStateles>(context, listen: false).updateCurrentIndex(index + 1);

     snackBarMessage(context);
   } else {
       log('File not found: ' + file.path);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    log('Error: ' + error.toString());
  }
 }

When the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not granted, the file is not deleted, and the mentioned error occurs. How can I delete the file and update the MediaStore properly without needing the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

For a better understanding of the issue, you can watch this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZhydQV3WFU&t=160s&ab_channel=YusufBarulay

In the video, console logs are showing that the file does not exists. Can you try with any other file that exists in the Download folder?

I tried with another file, and it also shows that the file does not exist.

Can you share a working example to reproduce the issue?

I'm looking for a solution on how to delete a file without using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Deleting works when I have MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, but doesn't work without it. Google Play doesn't accept MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Okay, permissions are required. It'll be a security breach otherwise.

Why do I need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to delete a file? There must be a way to get around this.

I retrieve audio files from local storage

This question is similar to: How to delete audio file without using "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission Android 11+. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Did you find any solutions ?
